# How to declare a variable of a class extending SQLiteOpenHelper in a fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, sqliteopenhelper

I must declare the following variable in a class extending Fragment:

```
public class CarrelloFragment  extends Fragment {

DatabaseHelper sqLite=new DatabaseHelper(this); //here is the error
```

The constructor of DatabaseHelper class does not allow to do this with a fragment.

Here is the code of the constructor of DatabaseHelper class that extends SQLiteOpenHelper:

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "MySupermarket.db";

```
private static final int SCHEMA_VERSION = 2;

public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, SCHEMA_VERSION);
}
```

Is there a way to declare a DatabaseHelper variable inside the fragment class?

Comment: Whenever you need `context` inside Fragment, always call `getActivity()` ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try `DatabaseHelper sqLite=new DatabaseHelper(getActivity());`